# Send email for each project owner including all notes and subtasks

Tags: javascript, email, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to write an Appscript/Javascript that can match a project to its tasks and notes relationship. Grab all the tasks + notes for each project and email the owner of the project. Im not sure how to do this at all. Since they are in three diffrent sheets.

Right now I have a script to send Weekly emails for each persons tasks assigned to them that works becasue it only requires the single IPTM_Task sheet.

My spreadsheet looks like this Tasks:
[Task Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nEhZY.png)

[image]

SubTasks:
[Subtasks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OahyL.png)

[image]

Notes:
[Notes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CspsA.png)

[image]

**Script to email task owners**

```
function sendEmails() {

  let s = '';
  const sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("ITPM_Tasks");
  const lastRow = sh.getLastRow();
  const startRow = 2; // First row of data to process
  const numRows = lastRow - 1; // Number of rows to process
  const rg = sh.getRange(startRow, 3, numRows, 6);
  const vs = rg.getValues();
  let oners = {pA:[]};
  vs.forEach((r,i) => {
    let [name,desc,status,owner,due] = r;
    if(status != 'Complete') {
     if(!oners.hasOwnProperty(owner)) {
       oners[owner]=[];
       oners[owner].push(r);
       oners.pA.push(owner)
     } else {
       oners[owner].push(r);
     }
    }
  });

  let subject = 'Weekly Reminder: The following tasks are assigned to you.';
  oners.pA.forEach(p => {
     let msg = `These Tasks below are assigned to you:\n`


    oners[p].forEach((r,i) => {
      let [name,desc,status,owner,due] = r;
        msg += `Task - ${i+1}\n`;
        msg += `Description: ${desc}\n`;
        msg += `Due Date: ${due.toDateString()}\n\n`
    });

    msg += `some message to task owners`;

MailApp.sendEmail(oners[p][0][3], subject, msg);
  });
}
```

EDIT:

- Basically, I would like the script to see the Project ID on the Task Sheet grab the project name (Project) and the Owner
  Then find the related "SubTask" Project Names" and related "Notes" to that project name

and send the Project owner an email with
Project Name
Subtask 1
subtask 2...
Note 1
Note 2
[idealoutput](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7SQt4.png)

Comment: The code looks familiar

Comment: Can you also clarify what seems to be the problem with your code or sheet? As well as where should the data come from which sheet or just a simple use case diagram would suffice

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have updated the post.

Answer (score 0):

Makes sense to break it down, e.g.like this:

```
const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
const projects = ss.getSheetByName("Task Sheet").getDataRange().getValues()

projects.forEach( project => {
  const projectId = project[0]
  const status = project[2]

  if( status.toLowerCase() == "completed") return

  const notes = getNotesByProjectId(projectId)
  const subtasks = getSubtasksByProjectId(projectId)

  // here you can build your message
  let message = ""

  notes.forEach( note => {
    // add conditions here
    message += note[2] + "\n"
  })

  subtasks.forEach( subtask => {
    // add conditions here
    message += subtask[3] + "\n"
  })

  // and then send it

  
})

function getNotesByProjectId( projectId ){
  const allNotes = ss.getSheetByName("Notes").getDataRange().getValues()
  // Filter where Column 2 (index 1) is the project
  const filteredNotes = allNotes.filter( note => note[1] == projectId )
  return filteredNotes 
}

function getSubtasksByProjectId( projectId ){
  const allNotes = ss.getSheetByName("Subtasks").getDataRange().getValues()
  // Filter where Column 3 (index 2) is the project
  const filteredNotes = allNotes.filter( note => note[2] == projectId )
  return filteredNotes 
}
```

#### Reference

- [Sheet.getDataRange](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getdatarange)